# web server(tomcat, jboss..etc) can communicate with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, jsp, tomcat, web

our team use both web server(tomcat or jboss)  and node js

my team member make  user management in web server. and

and he will send user session  to node js socket.

is it possible? for node js how to receive web socket connection from web server?

I use express, socket io,webrtc.io module in nodejs

Comment: Of course. Why would a server reading a socket care if it came from Tomcat or not? It wouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes web servers can communicate to the node js using curl, which hits url and process the response.